# How to delete value in cell B if cell A = yes

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to delete the value in cells B:B if value in A:A = yes

This is what I tried but doesnt work, maybe I placed the code in the wrong place ?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = yes Then
            Range("B" & Target.Row).Clear
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you place the code? It should be in a sheet code module. Also, best to loop - `If Target = 1` will fail if `Target` is more than one cell.

Comment: Where do you check for "yes"?

Comment: Your code and description do not match.  The code is checking B for `1` and clearing A.

Comment: I think you have your logic the wrong way round. Perform an `Intersect` on `Column A` and then check if `Target.Value` is **yes**. If it is, clear cell in `Column B`

Comment: @ScottCraner great minds and all of that :)

Comment: @JvdV Sorry, I just Edited my code.

Comment: So yes is a variable? I assume it's a string "yes"?

Comment: @JvdV yes it is a String

Comment: `If Target = "yes" Then` Then if it is not running and is located in the actual worksheet module and not a general code module, then you need to make sure the events are enabled.  Put `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the immediate window and hit Enter.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are typing or inserting values into column B. However, that will never intersect with column A. So no clearing happens when the A column cell in the same row holds "yes". Correct? That would be exactly opposite to what has been previously mentioned. Can you clarify which column you are entering values into. A or B?

Comment: `yes` is a variable and since it isn't *declared* or *set* the value of that variable is nothing. So when you do `If Target = yes Then` you are actually saying `If Target = "" Then` which is not your intention. String Literals need to be encased in double quotes;so instead: `If Target = "yes" Then`

Comment: @JvdV im entering values into column A. If value in column A = yes, I want the value in column B to be deleted.

Comment: @JNevill I tried using the double quotes but it still doesnt work!

Comment: That's probably due to the other reasons @ScottCraner mentioned. Make sure this code resides in your Worksheet's code, not in a "module". Ensure that `Application.EnableEvents` is toggled to `True`. Lastly, save the workbook at least once (that one trips me up sometimes). Also.. I believe it's `ClearContents` but perhaps `Clear` works as well... I've never used it.

Comment: It might be a silly question, but, theres already some code that is running on my worksheet code. How do i add another one? Where do I paste it ?. @JNevill